# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I'm facing this issue upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure here the my deployment and service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: project
  labels:
    app: project
    service: project
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9080
      name: http
  selector:
    app: project
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: project-svc
  labels:
    account: project
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: project-v1
  labels:
    app: project
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: project
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: project
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: project-svc
      containers:
        - name: project
          image: segullshairbutt/website:admin_project_a_01_cl1_wn1_pod1_c4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9080
```

and here are the `Gateway and virtualservice`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: project-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: projectinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - project-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    route:
    - destination:
        host: project
        port:
          number: 9080
```

when i visit using minikube-ip:istio-engress i get this error but when I just change the image from my to bookinfo product-page ther nothing this error. I don't know why this is and from where.
Please help me I'll be very thankful to you!

Comment: What application is throwing this error; How can I replicate it? What is engress? Did you mean egress or ingress?

Comment: I want deploy custom Swagger contsiners in istio kubernetes, inside ths cluster all the containers are running but when i try to access from outside using istio-ingress-gateway i got this error.

Comment: "ther nothing this error" - What does it mean?? Also you still didn't answer my question: "How can I replicate it?"

Comment: sorry @Matt  actually I'mnot getting what you're asking